# Grails: Event listener never stop (with websocket plugin)

Tags: mongodb, grails

I have a problem with my listener (platform core plugin).  It never stop after event (afterInsert) was triggered (Mongo standalone)

My service catch the event and use the *SimpMessagingTemplate* (websocket plugin) to send on topic the data (A news user registration). The data is saved, but the listener is triggered again and again.

p.s. The data not really saved, the consequent exception, rollback the transaction. But in debug mode I can see the assigned id.

```
@Transactional
class MessageEventService {

    SimpMessagingTemplate brokerMessagingTemplate

    @Listener(topic = 'afterInsert',namespace = 'gorm')
    void afterInsert(User user) {
       log.info("DIOBO")
       brokerMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/myEventTopic", "myEvent: User Add ${user.name}")
    }

}
```

And at the end...

```
    .[grails] Servlet.service() for servlet grails threw exception
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2367)
```

Why happens?!?!?

Thanks!